# Unique provider value for child component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-providers

I am trying to create a reusable date picker component. One of the features is that you can choose a `periodLevel`. Such as monthly daily or yearly. The problem I have is that when I call this component from a parent component I manipulate the period level using a `dateFormats` variable that I put in `useValue` in `providers`.
In the stackblitz I have recreated the situation and I call child1 component twice, once with a daily level and once with a monthly level:
[image]

Both date pickers appear with a monthly level (mm/yyyy), because the `dateFormats` variable is adjusted in such a way for the second child component.

Inside child1 component. I use the `dateFormats` variable in the `providers` of the component to manipulate the date formatting.
[image]

The problem is that I don't know how I can use a local variable inside `useValue` to avoid reusing the same `dateFormats` for all child components.
Desired result for the stackblitz example is that the first child component shows a daily level (dd/mm/yyyy) and the second child component shows monthly level (mm/yyyy).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qpa9x6?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my issue by making two adjustments.

1. use `useFactory` to generate a unique instance of the `dateFormats` variable (abstracted away in the `DataService`)
   [image]
2. Inject `MAT_DATE_FORMATS` into a local variable in the contructor of the component to be able to modify it --> `this.thisDateFormat`.

[image]

I can recommend the Angular University lesson on providers to anyone struggling with a similar issue: https://angular-university.io/lesson/angular-di-providers-injection-tokens